# how to solve problem exit status with 10 in device?

Tags: iphone, pdf, memory-management

I have implemented pdf reader application for ipad.Its working fine in simulator.But its terminated in device with exit status 10.I done know whats happning.Please help me solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John,

Most likely it is a memory leak that is causing the app to get killed for consuming too much memory.  Run the app with the `Leaks` tool (in the Run menu of XCode) and check how much memory gets allocated on load or during use.

Try it on the simulator first since you said it won't work on the device.  Also, be sure you are releasing all objects you create after using them (but only the ones you create, not the ones Apple does).

A good reference guide to memory management:  http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.pdf